# What does UniCoin Reputation to the max do

Tags: support, unicoins

I've just got my hands on stackoverflow's Unicoins.

At the powerup store, I can by "Repuation to the max".
The description is "Increase your own reputation by a settable factor".

That is very vague. I'm interested to know what that means exactly and how many reputations will I get by purchasing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can increase your reputation by up to a factor of 10!

Unfortunately it doesn't go up to 11.

[image: a failed attempt to make it go up to 11.]

Comment: I just need to mine another 42 rocks and I'll have enough rep to get into the top 0.01%!! Woot!!!

Comment: Neither does it get to -9 or 9.9 (you simply get an error). How unfortunate! I have always wanted negative rep :)

Comment: lol, should just multiply it by 1 ....

Answer (score 0):

When you purchase this powerup, you are prompted to enter a number between 1 and 10 (inclusive). Your current reputation is multiplied by this factor to determine your new reputation.