# Is it possible to use "Cut everyone's reputation by 10" multiple times

Tags: support, unicoins

I've used "Cut everyone's reputation by 10" already, and it is a great power - no need for me to learn anymore, I've got into the top 10 engineers with three mouse-clicks.

However, I'm sad because Jon Skeet still has more reputation than me. So, I was wondering, is it possible to use the powers multiple times (or will there be some power which could boost my reputation 6 times?).

Answer (score 7):

Yes, it is possible. You need to press extra hard with your mouse button on the "Cut everyone's reputation by 10" button, sort of like those carnival games that you hit with a hammer that make the weight hit the bell.

The harder you press, the more everyone else's reputation will decrease. It's kind of a sick way to show who's best.

Comment: Does this work on mobile too?

Comment: @Omega Yes, but you have to throw your phone on the ground instead.

Answer (score 6):

With enough Unicoins you can boost your reputation by *ten* times! Just get [reputation to the max](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/227525/152515). For a low price of 105 Unicoins, I'll even organise to ship it to you by tomorrow <sub>by which time it may have dematerialised</sub>

Comment: I think this is the right answer! Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

No you cannot do this unfortunately. Jon Skeet has special powers here and it's physically impossible!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible, do it in two steps:

1) Send 100 EUR to support conservation of the habitat of last unicorn http://www.birdlife.org/worldwide/support-us (don't get confused, birds serve only as flag species for unicorns, because stupid people do not believe unicorns exist)

2) Open Firefox Console and enter this code:

```
jQuery('.reputation-score').each(function () { jQuery(this).text(jQuery(this).text().slice(0, -1)) })
```

## Warning!!!

Do not even try 2) without 1) first, otherwise unicorns will run the jQuery line on your bank account!